# How can I convert a SQL script into Linq

Tags: sql, linq, count, group-by

I do have a sql script that I can't translate into linq. May one of you can help me out to get the right direction.

My big problems are the count and the group by:

```
SELECT
    wfs.ServerId,
    COUNT(wfss.Name) AS Records,
    wfs.DiskId
FROM WorkflowStep wfs
INNER JOIN WorkflowStepStatus wfss ON wfs.WorkflowStepStatusId = wfss.Id
WHERE wfs.WorkflowId = (
                            SELECT
                                Id
                            FROM Workflow wf
                            WHERE wf.Name = 'Collecting data virutal'
                        )
AND wfs.StepNumber IN (1, 2, 3)
AND wfss.Name = 'Processed'
GROUP BY    wfs.ServerId,
            wfss.Name,
            wfs.DiskId
```

Comment: Can you show a class model, so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible? Also, tell which LINQ flavor this should be. Did you try Linqer?

Comment: you can't compare `wfs.WorkflowId` with `(SELECT Id FROM Workflow wf
 WHERE wf.Name = 'Collecting data virutal')` you need to use `IN` operator, like `wfs.WorkflowId IN ( SELECT Id FROM Workflow wf WHERE wf.Name = 'Collecting data virutal')`, am i right ?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
var result = wfs.Join(wfss, 
    t => t.WorkflowStepStatusId, 
    u => u.ID, 
    (t, u) => new {
        t.ServerID,
        t.WorkflowId,
        t.StepNumber,
        u.Name,
        t.DiskID
    })
    .Where(t => t.WorkflowId == wf.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == "Collecting data virutal").ID &&
                t.Name == "Processed" &&
                new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.ToArray().Contains(t.StepNumber))
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.ServerID, t.Name, t.DiskID })
    .Select(t => new {
         t.Key.ServerID,
         Records = t.Key.Name.Count(),
         t.Key.DiskID
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: a simple correction: `t.Key.Name` has no method `Count`, instead of `t.Key.Name.Count()`, you can try this `Records = t.Count()`